# PhoneGap build: android-packageName tag doesn't works

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm using [PhoneGap build](https://build.phonegap.com) for generating different platforms version of my App.
Recently I lost my Android keystore file, so I had to recreate my Android App with another package name (to publish it on the Play Store).

For this, there is an useful option in the config.xml file of Cordova project:

```
<widget id="com.processingbox.packagename" version="1.0.6" android-packageName="com.processingbox.androidpackagename" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.processingbox.iospackagename" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

The "android-packageName" tag works well when I build the project on my computer but the PhoneGap build tool doesn't take this tag into account and the generated apk file has its package name equals to the one declared in the widget id ("com.processingbox.packagename" in my example).

For information, PhoneGap build my project thanks to a GIT repository which contains not the platforms folders (the platforms folders are generated thanks to the "platform" tags in the config.xml file).

Is there a way to inform PhoneGap build that the generated Android project must have a different package name from the one declared in the id tag?

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue, any ideas on how to solve this?